# search data for table template by django.can't not show next page >

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

i'm create template for search this table.it can search but click for next page is error in the picture

[image: 1]

For Error
[image: 2]

Same mycode.

```
@view.py
def search(request):

    query = request.GET.get('q1')
    qselect = request.GET.get('q2')
    qs = Record_data.objects.filter(Q(invoice_no__startswith=query) | Q(product=query))
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(qs, 5)
    try:
        page1 = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page1 = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page1 = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    template_name = 'status.html'
    context = {'object_list': page1}
```

#

page function
@html code

```
 {% if object_list.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if object_list.has_previous %}
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">Previous</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in object_list.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if object_list.number == i %}
        <li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">{{ i }}</span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if object_list.has_next %}
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ object_list.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">Next</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard coding why not use the data tables jquery plugin? 
https://datatables.net
use the above links and customise to your use ... i aint marketing but its simple to use a jquery plugin for data tables and hard coding will be easy for whole page Pagination.